# How to Write a New Row in Existing Excel File using PHP

Tags: java, php, .net, excel

I have an existing excel file.
i want to add data in this using my website.

Read/Write/Update Query

Help Me.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Assuming that it's a real Excel file, and not simply CSV masquerading as Excel, then use a library like [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using PHPExcel you would do this to write a single row:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$row = 1;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$row, $_POST['name']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$row, $_POST['email']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$row, $_POST['phone']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$row, $_POST['adress']);
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('myfile.xlsx');
```

Reading files involves starting here and working forward:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$data = $objReader->load('myfile.xlsx');
$objWorksheet = $data->getActiveSheet();
```

Obviously you'll need to do more digging into the docs to learn how to open existing files and append to them, but that hopefully gives you a kick in the right direction.